# Vscode opens file from local and full path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a workspace in `/home/my.name/dev/workspace/`, which I open from `/workspace`. When I open a file from the explorer view, the breadcrumbs shown the relative path, and when I swap between files in the editor, the explorer snaps to the active file.

My problem is, when i try to use code navigation ie. Clicking on a function to see where its declared, it opens up the file using the full path. This is annoying because if I click on a function defined in the file I have open, it opens another window with the full path to the file (the original `/workspace/..`, the new window at `/home/my.name/dev/workspace/..`

Any way to stop this? It's annoying and creates an inconsistent and inconvenient experience.

Comment: "_I have a workspace in /home/my.name/dev/workspace/, which I open from /workspace_" what is "/workspace" referring to here? there is no prior mention of such an absolute path in your question. "_it opens another window_" do you mean editor tab? Or actually a full-blown new VS Code window? What programming language are you writing in? Can you provide a [mre] of config and code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Project is a C++ one. In my case (which is probably similar to one reported by the OP), clicking either a function declaration or an include file will open another tab pointing to the full file path, in addition to the one holding the file relative to the project root.
Now [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3288) claims that this happens if your path includes symlinks, something that will happen due to a bug they didn't fix yet. I can say that I have the same problem even though my path has no symlinks.
Edit: Figured why it happens in my case, perhaps it will help you as well. So when I added the project to the workspace, I used the shortcut *Home* from the file explorer. This created the project relative to my home directory, which in turn gave me the same problem you had described. What solved my problem was the fact I instead added the project not from Home shortcut, but using the full path (i.e. Other Locations->Computer->Full path). From this point on, everything worked fine.